# Trying to use removeeventlistener after bind

Tags: javascript

So I have this situation where I need to listen to touchstart. Got that working fine but need to pass it parameters as there might be multiple of these listeners for different inputs. I found and tested this on stackoverflow. It works great using bind, but now my removeEventListener has gone tits up. I cannot figure out how to remove it, if I pass the parameters (which I want). Thanks.

```js
function some_func(otherFunc, ev) {
    // magic happens
}
someObj.addEventListener("click", some_func.bind(null, some_other_func), false);​
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a reference to the listener so you will be able to remove it.

```
var listener = some_func.bind(null, some_other_func);
someObj.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
...​
someObj.removeEventListener("click", listener, false);​
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was a better way of removing listeners rather than keeping track of all these listeners, but I guess this is how it will be... unique to every listener. Thanks again.

Comment: What kind of API do you expect to have for remove?